# Using find's -prune action

Tags: find

In this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current epoch time minus 1 second to be sure all files are captured. 
eptime=$((EPOCHSECONDS-1))

# Execute the commands that will do the sought for file changes:
gio set "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::trusted" no
gio set "/home/stephen/Desktop/Flameshot.desktop" "metadata::trusted" yes

# Create a test file to verify the script works
touch ./gio_set_file_changes_test.txt

# List all files changed after eptime
eptimestart=$EPOCHSECONDS
find / -name /proc/ -prune -o -newermt @$eptime -printf '%T+\t%s\t%p\n' 2>/dev/null | sort -r
echo Search time $((EPOCHSECONDS-eptimestart)) seconds
rm ./gio_set_file_changes_test.txt
```

The find command's -prune action fails to eliminate the /proc directory as intended. What is the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you hadn't redirected the standard error stream to /dev/null, you'd likely have seen a message:

```
find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains 
a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.
```

You probably want `-path` in place of `-name`:

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o -newermt "@$eptime" -printf '%T+\t%s\t%p\n' 2>/dev/null | sort -r
```

(note the absence of a trailing `/` on `/proc`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. -path instead of -name worked. :)